# Place call from iPhone 5 using SIM in iPhone 8

Tags: iphone, ios, sim

I'm apparently offered in iOS 13 on my iPhone 8, under "Calls on Other Devices", to make and receive calls on other devices. My iPhone 5 is listed and enabled as one of those devices.

In iOS 10 on my iPhone 5 I get the same offer, where instead my iPhone 8 shows up in the list. The two OSes obviously know about the feature — good. My iPhone 8 has my only SIM card, so I wanted to try this out using the 5, but I cannot figure out how to place a call this way?

- If I try to dial a number it fails immediately.
- The FaceTime app has no numpad.

I'm out of ideas. How is it supposed to be done?

I can answer incoming cellular calls on the iPhone 5 with no problems, so all prerequisites seem to be there.